# Is it possible to assert a failure in a Cypress Custom command?

Tags: javascript, cypress

How do I assert a failure from a [Cypress Custom Command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands)? Let's say I have a custom command with a complex set of tests that can fail due to some elements not being found, can I assert the failure of that line in a test file?

e2e/test.cy.ts:

```js
cy.someComplexCommand().should('fail')
```

support/commands.ts:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('someComplexCommand', () => {

  /* Some detailed DOM-traversing test */

})
```

The above is obviously sudo-code. The use case for this is that I have a complicated command that searches for a particular row in a table based on its' text content. While I use this most of the time to assert that something exists in the table, there are some tests that need to assert that it ***doesn't*** exist (like when I have just deleted the table row in the UI). Rather than write another command or more code in the test body, I'd prefer to keep it DRY and re-use the existing command, asserting a failure. Is this possible?

I've searched and there doesn't seem to be a lot of detail about asserting failures in Cypress.

### Real world example

support/commands.ts:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getTableRowContainingText', (text: string): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> => {

  return cy.get('table')
    .first()
    .find('tbody > tr > td')
    .filter(`:contains(${text})`)
    .first()
    .parent('tr')

})
```

e2e/test.cy.ts:

```js
cy.getTableRowContainingText('not-there').should('not.exist')
```

The above test fails because when a table is empty, my UI doesn't show a table at all:

[image]

Comment: Cypress doesn't really support testing things that aren't there (or may not be there).

Comment: There's a big hoo-har about DRY - do you make one command that does everything but isn't elegant (i.e hard to debug) or do you make many small focused commands that do only one thing well.

Comment: Fair point @AladinSpaz, but I guess it wouldn't be a hoo-har if it was straight forward to do. What I'm hearing is that, in Cypress, it's not straight forward to do. And in that scenario, I guess it becomes a hoo-har and then not worth doing.

Answer (score 4):

The `.should('not.exist')` only applies to the **query** immediately ahead of it.

If you comment out everything except `cy.get('table')` it passes (if it's the table that is missing).

You have created a command not a query, which is why `.should('not.exist')` does not have the expected effect of passing when the `<table>` does not exist.

Technically, you should define it as a [Custom Query](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-queries)

```js
Cypress.Commands.addQuery('getTableRowContainingText', (text) => {

  return (subject) => {
    return Cypress.$('table')
      .first()
      .find('tbody > tr > td')
      .filter(`:contains(${text})`)
      .first()
      .parent('tr')
  }
})

cy.getTableRowContainingText('not-there').should('not.exist')   // ✅ passes
```

The pattern is to return a ***synchronous*** function (no `cy.get()`) which the runner will call repeatedly until the timeout occurs.

The result of the inner return `return Cypress.$('table')...` is applied to the assertion `.should('not.exist')` and passes if they agree.

Note that negative assertions ***do not wait for the full timeout***. If the table appears after a couple of seconds, the assertion still passes because the table is ***initially*** not present.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I think I'm starting to understand why Cypress has been built like this. I'm guessing that using a custom query in this way is quite prone to unexpected behaviour due to not allowing the `get` command to search multiple times for the element?

Comment: Custom query also searches multiple times in the same way as `cy.get()`. If you put a `console.log('calling')` before `return Cypress.$('table')` you will see it do so.

Comment: Ah I see. But I'm assuming this is a problem with using any negative assertions i.e  `should('not.exist')` rather than the custom query itself? As in, would `get('table').should('not.exist')` pass if the DOM hadn't fully loaded? Or does it check several times before qualifying the assertion?